# Gridview template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm facing problem regarding the grid-view template. It shows sum of individual as well as shows grand total. How can it be tackle ?
I'm trying to design my grid same as shown in picture using C#.net.

Format for my grid-view:
[image]

Comment: IMO, you can't do this in the front-end. What I can suggest, iterate the `GridView` with a loop and check if there are multiple entries with the same name and get the totals of every individuals in the back-end. Forget about the grand total now.

Comment: post your code if you have tried.

Comment: you can probably do the total part using a Footer row in the grid.  Overall though you might be better using a Repeater or even nested Repeaters. You'll get more flexibility.

Comment: @Asif.Ali i'm binding data in gridview using list .this list is fetch from store procedure .
""

Comment: @Asif.Ali
`code` GridViewComm.DataSource = list;
                GridViewComm.DataBind();
                GridViewComm.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                GridViewComm.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                TableCellCollection cells = GridViewComm.HeaderRow.Cells;
                GridViewComm.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
               `code`

Comment: @juhinah you can follow this tutorial https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-sum-of-Columns-total-in-GridView-Footer-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx.

Comment: @juhinah if you have extra code please edit the question to include it. Code in comments is very difficult to read properly. Click the "edit" link just under your question (or this link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46068524/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with Asp.net Repeater control.Footer template will help you to hold summation

```
 <FooterTemplate>
                     <tr style="border-top: 1px solid Grey;">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <strong>Total</strong>
                        </td>

                           <td>
                            <strong></strong><asp:Label ID="CartTotal" runat="server" Text='0' /></strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                  </FooterTemplate>
```

in c# you will bind data like below

```
   CartListRepeater.DataSource = Yourdatasource;
                    CartListRepeater.DataBind();
```

Then add data to Footer after binding data.

```
Control FooterTemplate =CartListRepeater.Controls[CartListRepeater.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0];
Label lblFooter = FooterTemplate.FindControl("CartTotal") as Label;
                        lblFooter.Text = "0"//This is your total value;
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks all for your help.. My problem sorted by using datatable .since i have to get data from different list that come from my bll which make thing tricky .. 
Best Regards.